# What is the appropriate way to deal with blog post that start to rank on porn-related queries?

Tags: seo, negative-seo

In Google Search Console, I noticed a few of my blog posts have started to rank for porn-related queries. When I checked in ahrefs I saw a few hundreds of spammy links to my page through a redirect following this pattern: `www.example.com?URL=https://shortener.example/dasdsa`. It's confusing because none of those links link to my page with porn-related anchors, and none of those pages mention porn-related queries at all.

I want to assume that Google will know to ignore those links.

What do you think is the appropriate way to deal? Disavow? I have other option?

Comment: www.example.com?URL=https://shortener.example/dasdsa

Which of these example.com is your domain, and which is an external one?

Comment: `example.com` is a legit website that had a params with the pattern above that linked to my website `mysite.com` @MalteLandwehr

Comment: I have them on my sites too.  I haven't worried about it yet.  But what benefit do these sites obtain by adding these links?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to assume that Google will know to ignore those links.

Most of the time, that is a reasonable assumption.

> What do you think is the appropriate way to deal? Disavow?

IF these links are the source of your porn-related rankings, disavowing them is indeed a good idea. Ideally, disavow whole domains.

> In Google Search Console, I noticed a few of my blog posts have
> started to rank for porn-related queries. When I checked in ahrefs I
> saw a few hundreds of spammy links to my page [...] none of those links link to my page with porn-related anchors

This makes me curious and sounds like these links might not be related to the issue at all. Do you have access to a tool like ahrefs or SEMrush to check if the porn-related rankings and the backlinks started to appear at the same time?

These tools could also show you more/other backlinks than Google Search Console.

Also, do these links go to the specific articles that are ranking for porn-related terms?

Comment: I didn't find nothing weird on those pages can cause an issue. for sure not rank on porn queries. regarding the times that the links appears. base on ahrefs data the links start to came ~2 month before GSC note the spike of the porn queries. So its hard to say but I really cant think about smt else. probably disavow will be the solution, although not sure if disavow the root domain or only the specific link since some of them are legit website

Comment: What confuses me most is the fact that no links use porn-related anchor text or that no site is related to pornography

Answer (score 1):

**Not an Answer, just experience**
I don't know how but I started getting a few pron-related backlinks a few months ago. Most of them are gone now, but few remain. So, I Disavowed them.
Did not face any problems like yours.

John Mueller on the spammy link(search engine journal): https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-what-to-do-about-spammy-links-from-malicious-domains/449215/#close